# Is it possible to hide other paths with onclick?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have a topojson file that looks like the following (only one "node" represented here):

```
{  
 "type":"Polygon",
 "properties":{  
 "OBJECTID":156,
 "geoid10_1":360610009001000,
 "ALAND10": 0,
 "AWATER10": 16690,
 "latitude":40.7055747,
 "longitude":-74.010762,
 "cnt_client":5,
 "blocks_lis":"360610050004001|360593025011000|360610065001005",
 "Shape_Leng":0.00507281682202,
 "Shape_Area":0.000001463445362
},
"arcs":[  
[  
  671,
  672,
  673,
  674
 ]
]
}
```

and shows on a map Manhattan blocks, colored after the cnt_client value.
When the map loads avery block shows up from white when cnt_client is 0 to dark_blue when its 10.

Is it possible to have an on click function that does:
1) keep the block clicked displayed as is
2) keep the blocks in block_lis displayed as well (each block has a geoid10_1 identifier)
3) hide all the other blocks

?

[image]

```
pathes
                .data(topojson.feature(geodata,geodata.objects.collection).features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d",path)
                .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.properties.cnt_client); })
                .style("stroke",  "white")
                .style("stroke-width", "0.7")
                .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
                .on("click", function(d) {

                    ???

                }
```

Comment: certainly, but where is your code?

Comment: it seems it disappeared when i edited my question. Let me put it back

Comment: does each path have their `geoid10_1` value assigned as an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assign each path has their unique `geoid10_1` value as an `id`.  Then you can use a CSS not selector:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
  // show everyone
  d3.selectAll('path')
    .style('opacity', 1);
  // find the ids of ones to continue to show
  var notIds = [d.geoid10_1].concat(d.blocks_lis.split("|")),
      cssSelector = "path";
  // build a css selector string
  notIds.forEach(function(d1){
    cssSelector += ':not([id="' + d1 + '"])';
  });
  // hide those NOT in our list
  d3.selectAll(cssSelector)
    .style("opacity", 0);      
});
```

---

Here's some code showing the approach which hides everyone excepted the clicked one and the next one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
    <style>
      path {
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg width="300" height="300">
      <path id="1" d="M0,0L200,200"></path>
      <path id="2" d="M0,0L150,200"></path>
      <path id="3" d="M0,0L100,200"></path>
      <path id="4" d="M0,0L050,200"></path>
    </svg>
    <script>
      
      d3.selectAll('path')
        .data([{},{},{},{}])
        .on('click', function(d){
        
          console.log(d);
        
          d3.selectAll('path')
            .style('opacity', 1);
        
          if (d.toggle) {
            d.toggle = false;
            return;
          }
        
          var self = d3.select(this),
              id = +self.attr('id'),
              nId = (id < 4) ? id + 1 : 1;
              
          d3.selectAll('path:not([id="' + id + '"]):not([id="' + nId + '"])')
            .style('opacity', 0);
        
          d.toggle = true;
          
        })
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks MArk for this very detailed answer. I modified the code a little bit to adapt it: i changed `d.geoid10_1` into `d.properties.geoid10_1` and `d.blocks_lis` into `d.properties.blocks_lis`.
I also changed `.style('opacity', 0)` into `.style("fill", "white");` So the hidden blocks get white as the rest of the map, hence become 'hidden'. 
The problem im trying to solve now from your code is that once clicked EVERYTHING disappears instead of keeping the notIds list showing.

Comment: Alright i figured it out, i added an id value to all the pathes so it could understand your ids list: `.attr("id", function(d){return d.properties.geoid10_1;})`

Comment: A followup question if i may: once clicked only a few blocks still appears on the map (which is good), then if i click on one of them (so as a second click), it does not 're-activate' the hidden blocks that should appear now (because in the list of the block i clickes in the second place). Is there a way to make the new list of block to show up?

Comment: or maybe toggle off this function when click a second time?

Comment: I added a toggle variable: `var toggle = "0"` before the click then within the click event `if ( toggle == "0") {` then your code executes and makes `toggle = "1"`. I dont manage to find the correct code to execute `if (toggle == "1")` to revert back the view to what it was before the first click.

Comment: @user3700389, see edits to my code snippet above.  Generally, I'll stash the "toggle" state on the data-bound `d`.  That way you can tell if a user is clicking the same a second time.

Comment: you mean i should add a toggle properties to the input data?

Comment: @user3700389, yes, it's a common technique in d3 to keep element state in the data binding

Comment: following your advice, i add this `.attr("toggle", "false")` . It makes the toggle work, but only if i play with the opacity. My ultimate goal is to play with the fill, make it white when not in notIds and keep the color function for the rest. my problem seems to be the properties of only the clicked node are accessible at this point

Comment: to quickly explain why i cant use the opacity and want to use the fill instead: the sea blocks appear grey while the land blocks appear either white or colored (see the screenshot), using the opacity everything appears white and i lose the coastal shape

Comment: ok this trick seems to work it around: I changed the id value to `.attr("id", function(d){ 
     
      if (d.properties.AWATER10 != "0") { return "WATER";}
      else {return d.properties.GEOID10;}

     })`

Comment: so now every water block gets a WATER id, then in your piece of code :  `var notIds = [d.properties.GEOID10].concat(d.properties.blocks_lis.split("|")),
          cssSelector = 'path:not([id="WATER"])';

          notIds.forEach(function(d1){
         cssSelector += ':not([id="' + d1 + '"])';
          });`

Comment: so id WATER is part of cssSelector and thus be excluded by the opacity 0

Comment: @user3700389, I'm confused.  You have it all sorted now?

Comment: yes, it's working now. i gave a different ID to the water pathes, and added that ID to the ccsSelector list. So the opacity 0 does not apply to water blocks. Thanks a lot for your help, and sorry for confusion. I am learning as i do it....